# "Unable to parse HTTP response content" when creating ApiGateway::Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

When I tried to create API Gateway-> `GET` method with integration to Lambda function using AWS CloudFormation, I'm getting error:
 `CREATE_FAILED  AWS::ApiGateway::Resource  [my resource]  Unable to parse HTTP response content`.

Any idea ?!

Answer (score 1):

When specifying the MethodResponses, it's **mandatory** to include the status code.

This will fail with "unable to parse":

```
"MethodResponses": [{
  "ResponseModels": {
    "application/json": { "Ref": "myModel" }
} } ],
```

And this will succeed:

```
"MethodResponses": [{
  "ResponseModels": {
    "application/json": { "Ref": "myModel" }
  },
  "StatusCode": 200 
} ],
```

No, [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-methodresponse.html) doesn't say this. Nor does it give an example.

Comment: Thanks!  It is not solved my issue, so I used in swagger file to describe my API Gateway and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the issue and found that in the end there seems to be a quirk in the CloudFormation Designer which keeps removing the parentId for my resource.

Check your cloud formation template before uploading and confirm the ParentId is still in the resource definition.

`"myApiResource": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
      "Properties": {
        "RestApiId": {
          "Ref": "myRestApi"
        },
        "PathPart": "mypath",
        "ParentId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "myRestApi",
            "RootResourceId"
          ]
        }
      },`

Comment: Thanks!  it is look like you right, the CloudFormation designer removed the parentId from my resource, I add it again and now it is working.